# Installing MariaDB Alongside MySQL

Tags: 16.04, mysql, mariadb

I want to install MariaDB alongside MySQL. Under Windows install it is very easy because it only needs to change the port. While under Ubuntu it's a different story.

I did the following steps for installation but I always get this error message through `journalctl -xe` although `my.cnf` already exists and has a prober permissions!

```
mysqld[26621]: Could not open required defaults file: /opt/mariadb-data/my.cnf
mysqld[26621]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB Database.
```

**Installation steps:**

```
cd /opt
tar -zxvpf mariadb-10.2.14-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
ln -s mariadb-10.2.14-linux-x86_64 mariadb
mkdir mariadb-data
mkdir /opt/mariadb-data/tmp
groupadd --system mariadb
useradd -c "MariaDB Server" -d /opt/mariadb -g mariadb --system mariadb
cp my.cnf mariadb-data/my.cnf #see the content below
chown -R mariadb:mariadb mariadb-10.2.14-linux-x86_64/
chown -R mariadb:mariadb mariadb-data/
chmod -R 700 mariadb-data/
cd mariadb
scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mariadb --defaults-file=/opt/mariadb-data/my.cnf
cd ..
cp mariadb.service /etc/systemd/system/ #see the content below
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Result of `systemctl status mariadb.service` is:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB Database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)

systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB Database.
systemd[1]: Started MariaDB Database.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB Database.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB Database.
```

Result of `/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mariadb --ledir=/opt/mariadb/bin` is:

```
# /opt/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mariadb --ledir=/opt/mariadb/bin
180507 14:20:33 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
180507 14:20:33 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
180507 14:20:33 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

- /opt/mariadb-data/my.cnf

https://gist.github.com/mbnoimi/b9daceca0e0e21da86b048b9883c5edf

- /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service

https://gist.github.com/mbnoimi/5920301ff79dcb88aab3ef7fa459733e

- Permissions of `/opt`

`Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (0/root)   Gid: (0/root)`

- Permissions of `/opt/mariadb-data`

`Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (999/mariadb)   Gid: (999/mariadb)`

- Permissions of `/opt/mariadb-data/my.cnf`

`Access: (0700/-rwx------)  Uid: (999/ mariadb)   Gid: (999/ mariadb)`

Comment: The Git Hub links are dead.